# Could there be any issues naming a Django model "Model"?

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking through a new client's code and they named one of their Django models "Model."  Could this cause any issues since all models are considered models or no?

Comment: It can lead to a nameclass where one by accident inherits from that `Model`, and not the `Model` class of `django.db.models`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem naming a class `Model` as long as that `Model` is *not* used as super class for other models. Indeed, one can define a:

```
from django.db import models

class Model(models.Model):
    # …

class WrongOtherModel(Model):
    # …

class CorrectOtherModel(models.Model):
    # …
```

Here the `WrongOtherModel` will inherit from the `Model` class defined in the file, which is likely *not* what we want to do: only if you want to use the defined `Model` as supercass, you use `Model` as superclass. If you want to define another model, you can do this by inheriting from `models.Model`.

That being said, I would advise *not* to name a model `Model`, since it makes it more likely that such mistakes will happen, but perhaps more importantly: it can result in a lot of confusion if you have to explain how the modeling works.